# Will a SQL mirror from an earlier backup sync / catch-up to the principal?

Tags: sql-server

If I create a SQL mirror from a backup that was taken 12 hours ago will the mirror eventually catch up to the principal database?  How will I know when it is synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up Database Mirroring for a database, you have to restore a FULL and Transaction log backup with no recovery on the destination prior to configuring the mirror.  Are you meaning your transaction log backup is from 12 hours ago?

Comment: Yes.  Let's say I do restore from a backup that was taken 12 hours ago and the existing database has been doing new transaction for the past 12 hours,  Will those new transactions come over automatically once I start the mirror?

Comment: They should, as long as a new transaction log backup or other backup has not taken place on the principal in the interim to break or put a gap in the log chain.  Keeping in mind that during these 12 hours, the transaction log, not backed up on the principal could get very large while you are restoring the last log backup.